# font-display not being recognised by Pagespeed

Tags: pagespeed-insights

Getting red flagged for:

Ensure text remains visible during webfont load Leverage the font-display CSS feature to ensure text is user-visible while webfonts are loading

I have font-display: auto in my font declarations:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'lagosregular';
  src: url('../fonts/lagos-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
  url('../fonts/lagos-webfont.woff') format('woff');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  font-display: auto;
}
```

https://africankitchen.gallery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm testing your site on PSI but not getting the `Ensure text remains visible during webfont load`. Did it resolve itself? If you took some extra steps or different path to make it happen, consider answering your own question for others who find this.

Answer (score 0):

You're right, sorry, about two days later, it disappeared and I forgot to resolve this post.
It was odd and persistent for days, then it vanished without me doing anything else.
Thank you.